# Nested fields causing rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am facing this problem where nested field is causing a rollback on submit. I am using rails 5.

Here is the new and create actions of the controller

```
 def new
    @match = Match.new
    @match.heros.build
 end

 def create
    @match = cur_user.matches.build(matches_params)
    @match.save
  end
```

Here are the params

```
    def matches_params
       params.require(:match).permit(:map, heros_attributes: [:id, :hero])
    end
```

Simplified form_for

```
= form_for(@match) do |f|
    = f.label :map, value: "Map Played:"
    = f.select "map",
    [["Select Map", 0]

    = f.label :heros, value: "Hero Played:"
    = f.fields_for :heros do |h|
      = h.select "hero",
      [["Select Hero", 0]

  = f.submit "Submit"
```

In match.rb I have

```
has_many :heros, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :heros
```

and in hero.rb I have

```
belongs_to :match
```

I get a rollback on pressing submit and on running @match.errors.full_messages I get ["Heros match must exist"]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Views are in haml.

Comment: You defined your model association like `Match` has many `Heros`. So before creating `heros` you have to create `match` first. In this line `@match = cur_user.matches.build(matches_params)` you are creating/updating a `heros` with out creating a `match` first.

Answer (score 0):

The plural of **hero** is **heroes**, and not **heros**. Change your code so that it specifies `heroes` instead of `heros`, and retry.